# Voice calling using Wowza media server on android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, wowza

From past few days I have been working on various available possibilities to implement 
voice calling from one android device to another.

I am having **Wowza media server** installed on a linux machine and a `RTSP` client [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) on my mobile device (Android 4.4 Kitkat).
So far I have been successfully able to achieve the audio streaming from my mobile to another mobile using single stream. It works fine and the latency is quiet less 
(2-3 seconds).

Since I have to implement a voice call between two users, correct me if i am wrong
, I will require two streams. One stream for routing the audio data and another to listen to whats been streaming from the other end.

It is also working as I am able to transmit audio and listen to the other calling party as well but I am not happy with the varying latency and connection drops its introducing. The latency varies from 4-5 seconds to sometimes 9-10 seconds which is pretty bad for voice calling.
I tried to adjust buffer size of the default `MediaPlayer` but its not also possible as its hidden down into architecture.

Following are my calibrations.

- Audio streaming parameters

  - AAC encoder
  - 8000 sampling rate
  - 16000-32000 bitrate
- Configurations of devices used for testing

  - Android 4.4 Kitkat (CM11) / Android 4.0 ICS / Android 4.1.2 JellyBean
  - 512 MB to 768 MB RAM
  - 1 GHZ Processor

Please suggest me what could be the problem or whats am I missing. I am currently going for Wowza but I am open suggestions to use any other streaming solutions.